# Subdomains rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I have a simple question I can't figure out.

I have a rails 3 app using subdomains.

A firm have many users. When a user log in, I want to redirect them to their firms subdomain.

I've used Ryan Bates screencast to get subdomains working.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

In my user_sessions_controller I have.

```
def create
@user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

if @user_session.save
  @firm = current_user.firm
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
  redirect_to root_url(:subdomain => @firm.subdomain)
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
```

end

This sends the user in the firm with subdomain lizz to this url

```
http://lvh.me:3000/?subdomain=lizz
```

when the user is logged in this link works

```
<%= link_to current_firm.subdomain, root_url(:subdomain => current_firm.subdomain) %>
```

Do you have any ideas on how to redirect from the controller to the subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you problem is that you are url the named url `root_url`. The helper method `url_for` that you modified (if you followed the Railscasts closely) is probably not used for the named url.

Try using `url_for` instead.

*Edit*

The names urls are generated in actionpack-3.0.x/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb and will not use your custom `url_for` method. However, does support a `:host` parameter so you need to write something like

```
... root_url(:host => "#{current_firm.subdomain}.domain.tld") ...
```

Comment: This will not pass over the cookie. So the user has to login again. Is there a way to transfere the cookie to the subdomain without (:domain => :all) option in the session_store.rb. If I use this the user get access to all firms

Comment: I looked into this a bit the other day and I don't think it is possible OOTB. Warden can handle multiple scopes which means that you could define something like firm scopes - however, Devise scopes match the warden scopes and I imagine that it would not be a working solution